# Maven build error - Mule 3.4.0 project cannot find jaxen-1.1.1-osgi depedency

Tags: maven, mule

I'm running into some problems building an old Mule 3.4.0 project (which I would prefer to not have to upgrade, if at all possible).  Specifically, Maven seems unable to resolve this dependency:

```
Failed to collect dependencies at org.mule.transports:mule-transport-vm:jar:3.4.0 -> org.mule.modules:mule-module-xml:jar:3.4.0 -> jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1-osgi: Failed to read artifact descriptor for jaxen:jaxen:jar:1.1.1-osgi: Could not transfer artifact jaxen:jaxen:pom:1.1.1-osgi
```

There is actually a fair bit of advice on this issue out there (including a migration help page from Codehaus) but, as of April 2016, all of it has so far left me in dead ends.

I've scoured the web trying to find this jaxen-1.1.1-osgi dependency and cannot find it anywhere (though you can find the non-osgi 1.1.1 all over the place).

Comment: Looks like some problems with firewall/proxy ? ` Could not transfer artifact jaxen:jaxen:pom:1.1.1-osgi`?  But the real problem here is that the given artifact does not exist: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22%20jaxen%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jaxen%22%20AND%20v%3A%221.1.1-osgi%22

Comment: I don't really consider this a fix/answer (more of a hack), but I was able to get around this by manually going to my AnypointStudio directory, locating this jar (/Users/<username>/Documents/AnypointStudio/plugins/org.mule.tooling.server.3.4.0_5.0.0.201412091416/mule/opt/jaxen-1.1.1-osgi.jar), then manually installing it into my local repo using this command: "mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=jaxen-1.1.1-osgi.jar -DgroupId=jaxen -DartifactId=jaxen -Dversion=1.1.1-osgi -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the dependency you are looking for: https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1-osgi/

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do to resolve this is to look at the graph of the dependencies.

You can do this from the command line with the maven dependency plugin, but the best visualizer is in NetBeans.

After installing NetBeans, all you have to do is to open project navigating to the pom, which opens the maven project (NetBeans understands Maven projects natively) and then open the pom file in the editor and click on Graph.

That will show you the entire graph of dependencies and transitives and let you even search for one, zoom in, etc.

It is going to save you lots of time also when trying to understand dependency conflicts.